# Git merge (or rebase) branch but only to a specific commit

Tags: git, merge

Here is my situation:

```
A                      master
 \
  \-- B --- C --- D    topic
```

I want to merge topic branch to master but only to commit C without changes introduced in commit D. I know I can create new branch from topic (topic_b), revert there to C and merge topic_b into master, but I'm not sure if there will be problems with how readable history is later when I want to merge full topic (with changes in D) into master. Is there other cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as `git merge C` or `git merge topic^`

Comment: Especially since this is a "fast forward" merge; but note that this works even if you do a "full" merge (with `--no-ff` for instance)—but then you may wish to edit the merge message a bit, since git won't know it's (sort of) a topic-branch merge.

Comment: @torek: If you specify `topic^`, then Git will put something alike to `merging topic (early part)` into your merge message.